# IOExcepion no Samsung para pegar arquivo Media Player

Tags: android

Pessoal estou com um probleminha, estou executando um video no background de um layout, em outros aparelhos funciona normal mas no samsung não consigo acessar o vídeo e tomo a exception

```
  java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:939)
```

Código

```
  Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.app_video_medium);

        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), video);
        mp.prepare();
```

Alguém sabe porque?

Comment: Verifique se você tem permissão e se o `Uri` está correto.

Comment: tenho permissão e a URI esta correta, esse erro só acontece nos celulares samsung, teste em um asus e um sony funcionou